# Error connection to Epson TM-T20II

Tags: javascript, sdk, epson, epos

I have some problems setting up my Epson TM-T20II POS printer. My goal is to be able to have a webpage on an external hosted webserver and print from that webpage some php code to my POS printer.

I downloaded the ePOS SDK JavaScript (v2.6.0) (downloaded via [this URL](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5595&pcat=3&scat=57&ml_lang=nl) to make the connection from the webserver towards the Epson printer. In the SDK, there is also a test folder which contains some test webpages to test the functionality.

When I open the printer_sample.html webpage locally, I can make a successfull connection to the printer: [connected to ePOS Device Service Interface. You can use printer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Rbc.png)

When I upload the complete folder to my hosting company and try the same, I get the following error message: [connected to ePOS Device Service Interface is failed. [ERROR_TIMEOUT]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKeYG.png). Off course, I did filled in my public IP address correctly.

I did checked my router which is connected to the router of my ISP. (My router is placed in the ISP routers's DMZ zone). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urREw.png) you find a tcpdump of my router:

- 192.168.0.200 is the IP address of the ticket printer
- 192.168.99.1 is the default gateway of my ISP router

So you can see in the tcpdump that the request is send properly to the ticket printer, and the ticket printer is sending a reply but the handshake isn't finished.

Does anybody has an idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance
Sven

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck in the JS SDK here, I successfully connected printer and I can print wirelessly but when I try to print via ePOS JS SDK it gives me two lines of junk character

my conclusion :

A printer connected properly it detects IP & port properly but I don't know why it prints junk.

I used the ePOS JS sample file so I am sure the code is not wrong.